# Getting ValueMember from selected item in a ListBox with C#

Tags: c#, listbox, selecteditem, valuemember

I'm trying to get all the selected items ValueMember from a ListBox with C#.

For ex.:

I've a list like this:

```
ID | Name and Lastname
----------------------
1  | John Something
2  | Peter Something2
3  | Mary Smith
```

This structure is part of my ListBox. I've builded this listbox with this code:

```
private void fill_people_listBox()
{
    this.listBoxPeople.DataSource = db.query("SELECT ....");
    this.listBoxPeople.DisplayMember = "people_name_last";
    this.listBoxPeople.ValueMember = "people_id"; 
}
```

The ListBox is successfully populated. When the user wants to save the changes I've to loop throught this list to get all the selected items, but I do not need the Item, I need the ID.

Ex.:

```
1 | John Something.
```

Ignore John Something, get 1, so I do not need the DisplayMember, only the ValueMember.

To do this I've try several ways with the following:

1º

```
        foreach (ListBox selectedItem in this.listBoxGarantes.SelectedItems)
        {
            selectedItem.ToString(); // just an example, I'm printing this.

        }
```

2º

```
        string strItem;

        // insert garantes
        foreach (object selectedItem in this.listBoxGarantes.SelectedItems)
        {
            strItem = selectedItem as String;

            strItem; // just an example, I'm printing this.
        }
```

3º And this last one among others.

```
        foreach (ListViewItem element in this.listBoxGarantes.Items)
        {
            if (element.Selected)
            {
                element.SubItems[0].Text; // just an example, I'm printing this.
            }
        }
```

I've try several options, but I wasn't able to get succesfully the ID for each element. I do not know what else to do.

I hope anyone can help me.

Regards.

Comment: Try just `this.listBoxPeople.SelectedValue`

Comment: But I've several selected values. Where should I put this.listBoxPeople.SelectedValue?

Comment: Then use your first snippet and replace ListBox with just var, and then you will have to cast the object to what it is, which isn't clear what db.query is returning.  DataRows from a DataTable?

Comment: Yes, it's a DataTable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have multiple selections, the SelectedValue property won't help you much since you are enumerating through the SelectedItems list.

Try casting your items back into a DataRowView object:

```
foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems) {
  MessageBox.Show("ID = " + ((DataRowView)item)["people_id"].ToString());
}
```